# <f:validateRegex> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid

Tags: java, jsf

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
 <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="adres_defteri">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="E-posta Adresiniz:"/>
            <h:inputText id="isim" value="#{degiskenBean.eposta}" required="true" validatorMessage="Geçersiz E-posta"  requiredMessage="E-Posta Alanı Zorunludur" />
                        <f:validateRegex pattern="^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,6}))?$"/>
            <h:message for="eposta" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="GÖNDER" action="sonuc.xhtml" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Error

> /index.xhtml @xxxxx  Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@5790b5bb

I already checked similar question, but they didn't help.

IDE: NetBeans

Server: GlassFish

Comment: Next time, as requested in [ask], keep track of what Q/A you tried, mention them and mention why they did not help. And you totally forget what you want to validate... Since the error is totally valid, you have it as a child of the panelgrid instead you most likely want to make it a child of the inputText

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<h:inputText id="isim" value="#{degiskenBean.eposta}" required="true" validatorMessage="Geçersiz E-posta"  requiredMessage="E-Posta Alanı Zorunludur" >
   <f:validateRegex pattern="^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,6}))?$"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="eposta" />
```

`f:validateRegex` should be in `h:inputText` tag

Comment: if i try this, i took this error: "/index.xhtml @22,144 <f:inputText> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: inputText"